# How to Optimize execution time for RGB to HSL conversion function?

Tags: javascript, optimization, rgb, hsl

I've created this function to convert RGB color to HSL color. It works perfect.

But I need to make it run faster, because it's used to replace colors on a canvas, and I need to reduce the time of replacement. Since the image contains 360k pixels (600x600px) anything can make it faster.

That's my current implementation:

```
/**
 * Convert RGB Color to HSL Color
 * @param {{R: integer, G: integer, B: integer}} rgb
 * @returns {{H: number, S: number, L: number}}
 */
Colorize.prototype.rgbToHsl = function(rgb) {
    var R = rgb.R/255;
    var G = rgb.G/255;
    var B = rgb.B/255;
    var Cmax = Math.max(R,G,B);
    var Cmin = Math.min(R,G,B);
    var delta = Cmax - Cmin;
    var L = (Cmax + Cmin) / 2;
    var S = 0;
    var H = 0;

    if (delta !== 0) {
        S = delta / (1 - Math.abs((2*L) - 1));

        switch (Cmax) {
            case R:
                H = ((G - B) / delta) % 6;
                break;
            case G:
                H = ((B - R) / delta) + 2;
                break;
            case B:
                H = ((R - G) / delta) + 4;
                break;
        }
        H *= 60;
    }

    // Convert negative angles from Hue
    while (H < 0) {
        H += 360;
    }

    return {
        H: H,
        S: S,
        L: L
    };
};
```

Comment: One optimization would be to remove that `while` loop and instead do `if (H < 0) H = -(H % 360)`. If I'm not mistaken, that will give you the same result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## tl;dr

- Define everything, before calculations
- Switch is bad for performance
- Loops are bad
- Use Closure Compiler for automated optimizations
- MEMOIZE! (this one is not available in the benchmark because it uses only one color at the time)
- Compare pairs in `Math.max` and `Math.min` (`if-else` works better for bigger numbers as far as I can see)

### Benchmark

The benchmark is quite basic; I'm generating a random RGB color every time and use it for the test suit.

The same color for all implementations of a converter.

I'm currently using a fast computer, so your numbers may differ.

At this point it is hard to optimize further, because performance differs, depending on the data.

### Optimisations

Define the object for the result value at the very beginning. Allocating memory for the objects upfront somehow improves the performance.

```
var res = {
    H: 0,
    S: 0,
    L: L
}
// ...
return res;
```

Not using `switch` will yield easy performance improvement.

```
if (delta !== 0) {
    S = delta / (1 - Math.abs((2 * L) - 1));

    if (Cmax === R) {
        H = ((G - B) / delta) % 6;
    } else if (Cmax === G) {
        H = ((B - R) / delta) + 2;
    } else if (Cmax === B) {
        H = ((R - G) / delta) + 4;
    }
    H *= 60;
}
```

While loop is easily removable by:

```
if (H < 0) {
    remainder = H % 360;

    if (remainder !== 0) {
        H = remainder + 360;
    }
}
```

I have also applied [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) to remove redundant operations inside of the code.

You should **memoize** the results!

Consider refactoring the function to use three arguments so it's possible to have a multi-dimensional hash-map for memozing cache. Alternatively you can try using [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap), but the performance of this solution is unknown.

See the article [Faster JavaScript Memoization For Improved Application Performance](https://addyosmani.com/blog/faster-javascript-memoization/)

### Results

#### Node.js

The best one is `rgbToHslOptimizedClosure`.

```
node -v
v6.5.0

rgbToHsl x 16,468,872 ops/sec ±1.64% (85 runs sampled)
rgbToHsl_ x 15,795,460 ops/sec ±1.28% (84 runs sampled)
rgbToHslIfElse x 16,091,606 ops/sec ±1.41% (85 runs sampled)
rgbToHslOptimized x 22,147,449 ops/sec ±1.96% (81 runs sampled)
rgbToHslOptimizedClosure x 46,493,753 ops/sec ±1.55% (85 runs sampled)
rgbToHslOptimizedIfElse x 21,825,646 ops/sec ±2.93% (85 runs sampled)
rgbToHslOptimizedClosureIfElse x 38,346,283 ops/sec ±9.02% (73 runs sampled)
rgbToHslOptimizedIfElseConstant x 30,461,643 ops/sec ±2.68% (81 runs sampled)
rgbToHslOptimizedIfElseConstantClosure x 40,625,530 ops/sec ±2.70% (73 runs sampled)

Fastest is rgbToHslOptimizedClosure
Slowest is rgbToHsl_
```

#### Browser

```
Chrome Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)

rgbToHsl x 18,456,955 ops/sec ±0.78% (62 runs sampled)
rgbToHsl_ x 16,629,042 ops/sec ±2.34% (63 runs sampled)
rgbToHslIfElse x 17,177,059 ops/sec ±3.85% (59 runs sampled)
rgbToHslOptimized x 27,552,325 ops/sec ±0.95% (62 runs sampled)
rgbToHslOptimizedClosure x 47,659,771 ops/sec ±3.24% (47 runs sampled)
rgbToHslOptimizedIfElse x 26,033,751 ops/sec ±2.63% (61 runs sampled)
rgbToHslOptimizedClosureIfElse x 43,430,875 ops/sec ±3.55% (59 runs sampled)
rgbToHslOptimizedIfElseConstant x 33,696,558 ops/sec ±3.97% (58 runs sampled)
rgbToHslOptimizedIfElseConstantClosure x 44,529,209 ops/sec ±3.56% (60 runs sampled)

Fastest is rgbToHslOptimizedClosure
Slowest is rgbToHsl_
```

### Run the benchmark yourself

Note, that browser will freeze for a moment.

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var RGB = { R: getRandomInt(0, 255), G: getRandomInt(0, 255), B: getRandomInt(0, 255) }

// http://axonflux.com/handy-rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-c

/**
 * Converts an RGB color value to HSL. Conversion formula
 * adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space.
 * Assumes r, g, and b are contained in the set [0, 255] and
 * returns h, s, and l in the set [0, 1].
 *
 * @param   {number}  r       The red color value
 * @param   {number}  g       The green color value
 * @param   {number}  b       The blue color value
 * @return  {Array}           The HSL representation
 */
function rgbToHsl_(r, g, b) {
    r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
    var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
    var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

    if (max == min) {
        h = s = 0; // achromatic
    } else {
        var d = max - min;
        s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
        switch (max) {
            case r:
                h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0);
                break;
            case g:
                h = (b - r) / d + 2;
                break;
            case b:
                h = (r - g) / d + 4;
                break;
        }
        h /= 6;
    }

    return [ h, s, l ];
}

function rgbToHsl(rgb) {
    var R = rgb.R / 255;
    var G = rgb.G / 255;
    var B = rgb.B / 255;
    var Cmax = Math.max(R, G, B);
    var Cmin = Math.min(R, G, B);
    var delta = Cmax - Cmin;
    var L = (Cmax + Cmin) / 2;
    var S = 0;
    var H = 0;

    if (delta !== 0) {
        S = delta / (1 - Math.abs((2 * L) - 1));

        switch (Cmax) {
            case R:
                H = ((G - B) / delta) % 6;
                break;
            case G:
                H = ((B - R) / delta) + 2;
                break;
            case B:
                H = ((R - G) / delta) + 4;
                break;
        }
        H *= 60;
    }

    // Convert negative angles from Hue
    while (H < 0) {
        H += 360;
    }

    return {
        H: H,
        S: S,
        L: L
    };
};

function rgbToHslIfElse(rgb) {
    var R = rgb.R / 255;
    var G = rgb.G / 255;
    var B = rgb.B / 255;
    var Cmax = Math.max(R, G, B);
    var Cmin = Math.min(R, G, B);
    var delta = Cmax - Cmin;
    var L = (Cmax + Cmin) / 2;
    var S = 0;
    var H = 0;

    if (delta !== 0) {
        S = delta / (1 - Math.abs((2 * L) - 1));

        if (Cmax === R) {
            H = ((G - B) / delta) % 6;
        } else if (Cmax === G) {
            H = ((B - R) / delta) + 2;
        } else if (Cmax === B) {
            H = ((R - G) / delta) + 4;
        }
        H *= 60;
    }

    // Convert negative angles from Hue
    while (H < 0) {
        H += 360;
    }

    return {
        H: H,
        S: S,
        L: L
    };
};

function rgbToHslOptimized(rgb) {
    var R = rgb.R / 255;
    var G = rgb.G / 255;
    var B = rgb.B / 255;
    var Cmax = Math.max(Math.max(R, G), B);
    var Cmin = Math.min(Math.min(R, G), B);
    var delta = Cmax - Cmin;
    var S = 0;
    var H = 0;
    var L = (Cmax + Cmin) / 2;
    var res = {
        H: 0,
        S: 0,
        L: L
    }
    var remainder = 0;

    if (delta !== 0) {
        S = delta / (1 - Math.abs((2 * L) - 1));

        switch (Cmax) {
            case R:
                H = ((G - B) / delta) % 6;
                break;
            case G:
                H = ((B - R) / delta) + 2;
                break;
            case B:
                H = ((R - G) / delta) + 4;
                break;
        }
        H *= 60;
    }

    if (H < 0) {
        remainder = H % 360;

        if (remainder !== 0) {
            H = remainder + 360;
        }
    }

    res.H = H;
    res.S = S;

    return res;
}

function rgbToHslOptimizedIfElse(rgb) {
    var R = rgb.R / 255;
    var G = rgb.G / 255;
    var B = rgb.B / 255;
    var Cmax = Math.max(Math.max(R, G), B);
    var Cmin = Math.min(Math.min(R, G), B);
    var delta = Cmax - Cmin;
    var S = 0;
    var H = 0;
    var L = (Cmax + Cmin) / 2;
    var res = {
        H: 0,
        S: 0,
        L: L
    }
    var remainder = 0;

    if (delta !== 0) {
        S = delta / (1 - Math.abs((2 * L) - 1));

        if (Cmax === R) {
            H = ((G - B) / delta) % 6;
        } else if (Cmax === G) {
            H = ((B - R) / delta) + 2;
        } else if (Cmax === B) {
            H = ((R - G) / delta) + 4;
        }
        H *= 60;
    }

    if (H < 0) {
        remainder = H % 360;

        if (remainder !== 0) {
            H = remainder + 360;
        }
    }

    res.H = H;
    res.S = S;

    return res;
}

function rgbToHslOptimizedIfElseConstant(rgb) {
    var R = rgb.R * 0.00392156862745;
    var G = rgb.G * 0.00392156862745;
    var B = rgb.B * 0.00392156862745;
    var Cmax = Math.max(Math.max(R, G), B);
    var Cmin = Math.min(Math.min(R, G), B);
    var delta = Cmax - Cmin;
    var S = 0;
    var H = 0;
    var L = (Cmax + Cmin) * 0.5;
    var res = {
        H: 0,
        S: 0,
        L: L
    }
    var remainder = 0;

    if (delta !== 0) {
        S = delta / (1 - Math.abs((2 * L) - 1));

        if (Cmax === R) {
            H = ((G - B) / delta) % 6;
        } else if (Cmax === G) {
            H = ((B - R) / delta) + 2;
        } else if (Cmax === B) {
            H = ((R - G) / delta) + 4;
        }
        H *= 60;
    }

    if (H < 0) {
        remainder = H % 360;

        if (remainder !== 0) {
            H = remainder + 360;
        }
    }

    res.H = H;
    res.S = S;

    return res;
}

function rgbToHslOptimizedIfElseConstantClosure(c) {
    var a = .00392156862745 * c.h, e = .00392156862745 * c.f, f = .00392156862745 * c.c, g = Math.max(Math.max(a, e), f), d = Math.min(Math.min(a, e), f), h = g - d, b = c = 0, k = (g + d) / 2, d = {
        a: 0,
        b: 0,
        g: k
    };
    0 !== h && (c = h / (1 - Math.abs(2 * k - 1)), g === a ? b = (e - f) / h % 6 : g === e ? b = (f - a) / h + 2 : g === f && (b = (a - e) / h + 4), b *= 60);
    0 > b && (a = b % 360, 0 !== a && (b = a + 360));
    d.a = b;
    d.b = c;
    return d;
};

function rgbToHslOptimizedClosure(c) {
    var a = c.f / 255, e = c.b / 255, f = c.a / 255, k = Math.max(Math.max(a, e), f), d = Math.min(Math.min(a, e), f), g = k - d, b = c = 0, l = (k + d) / 2, d = {
        c: 0,
        g: 0,
        h: l
    };
    if (0 !== g) {
        c = g / (1 - Math.abs(2 * l - 1));
        switch (k) {
            case a:
                b = (e - f) / g % 6;
                break;
            case e:
                b = (f - a) / g + 2;
                break;
            case f:
                b = (a - e) / g + 4;
        }
        b *= 60;
    }
    0 > b && (a = b % 360, 0 !== a && (b = a + 360));
    d.c = b;
    d.g = c;
    return d;
}

function rgbToHslOptimizedClosureIfElse(c) {
    var a = c.f / 255, e = c.b / 255, f = c.a / 255, g = Math.max(Math.max(a, e), f), d = Math.min(Math.min(a, e), f), h = g - d, b = c = 0, l = (g + d) / 2, d = {
        c: 0,
        g: 0,
        h: l
    };
    0 !== h && (c = h / (1 - Math.abs(2 * l - 1)), g === a ? b = (e - f) / h % 6 : g === e ? b = (f - a) / h + 2 : g === f && (b = (a - e) / h + 4), b *= 60);
    0 > b && (a = b % 360, 0 !== a && (b = a + 360));
    d.c = b;
    d.g = c;
    return d;
}

new Benchmark.Suite()
    .add('rgbToHsl', function () {
        rgbToHsl(RGB);
    })
    .add('rgbToHsl_', function () {
        rgbToHsl_(RGB.R, RGB.G, RGB.B);
    })
    .add('rgbToHslIfElse', function () {
        rgbToHslIfElse(RGB);
    })
    .add('rgbToHslOptimized', function () {
        rgbToHslOptimized(RGB);
    })
    .add('rgbToHslOptimizedClosure', function () {
        rgbToHslOptimizedClosure(RGB);
    })
    .add('rgbToHslOptimizedIfElse', function () {
        rgbToHslOptimizedIfElse(RGB);
    })
    .add('rgbToHslOptimizedClosureIfElse', function () {
        rgbToHslOptimizedClosureIfElse(RGB);
    })
    .add('rgbToHslOptimizedIfElseConstant', function () {
        rgbToHslOptimizedIfElseConstant(RGB);
    })
    .add('rgbToHslOptimizedIfElseConstantClosure', function () {
        rgbToHslOptimizedIfElseConstantClosure(RGB);
    })
    // add listeners
    .on('cycle', function (event) {
        console.log(String(event.target));
    })
    .on('complete', function () {
        console.log('Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').map('name'));
        console.log('Slowest is ' + this.filter('slowest').map('name'));
    })
    // run async
    .run({ 'async': false });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bestiejs/benchmark.js/master/benchmark.js"></script>
```

Comment: Very nice answer. Big candidate to win the bounty! :)
I'll do the tests soon! Thanks

Comment: Did you try replacing `x / 255` with `x * 0.00392156862745`?

Comment: @ConnorsFan yes, it yields somewhat ambiguous results for me. I will update the benchmark.

Comment: Definitively that's the best answer. I'm not using exactly your code, but I gave me the path to follow.

I realized that to my operation (colorize a image), I don't need the original H and S, only the L part of HSL, so I reduced my function from `rgbToHsl` to `rgbToL`.


After all optimizations, that's the final result:
`function(R, G, B) {
        var L;

        if (R < G && R > B) {
            L = G + B;
        } else if (G < R && G > B) {
            L = R + B;
        } else {
            L = G + R;
        }

        return L / 510;
    }
`

Comment: Also a tip to make the benchmark more realistic:
Instead of using a random RGB, I'm using every RGB possible, because I found that some specific colors are faster than others.

Comment: @EliasSoares Happy to help!

Answer (score 4):

Avoid the divisions by all means. You can probably eliminate a few by rescaling the relevant variables and constants.

You can also avoid divisions by using a lookup-table of inverses.

I don't think that the switch case is very efficient. I would advise to replace the max/min/switch by a single discussion using a triply nested `if` where you compare the RGB components, ending in the 6 possible orderings and applying ad-hoc processing to each.

Comment: I did replaced the min/max calls by two blocks of if-elseif-else and the execution time reduced a lot. I will try to avoid the switch also and post the result.

Answer (score -1):

Use a rough approximation instead:

```
third = Math.PI * 2 / 3;
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb('+ [
    127 + 127 * Math.cos(time - third),
    127 + 127 * Math.cos(time),
    127 + 127 * Math.cos(time + third)
] +')';
```

Based on:

- http://www.p01.org/artjs_at_ffconf/
- http://www.p01.org/artjs_at_ffconf/talk.html

Comment: This answer doesn't apply:
- I need precision
- I need the HSL to make transformations.